# Unable to start the rails applicaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got application which runs on rails 2.3.11. I have created a separate gem set to configure application.

All the gems that are required are installed but when I try to start the server it gives me an error as follows

```
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

/home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- active_record/acts/list (MissingSourceFile)

from /home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'

from /home/re5/Documents/Client:Applications/LMFT/vendor/plugins/acts_as_list/init.rb:2:in `evaluate_init_rb'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'

from /home/re5/Documents/Client:Applications/LMFT/config/../vendor/plugins/engines/lib/engines/plugin.rb:44:in `load'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'

from /home/re5/Documents/Client:Applications/LMFT/config/environment.rb:20

from /home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@lmft_new/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84

from /home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'

from /home/re5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Can any one help me on this. I'm unable to figure out what was the problem and I tried my best with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stacktrace suggests you miss acts_as_list plugin. You can find it here: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: But I have the acts_as_list plugin installed in my vendor directory.

Comment: So it's a strange thing. I'm thinking about it, if I come up with something I'll add a comment here...

Comment: Just no I have replaced my acts_as_list plug-in with source that you have suggested the error is still preceding.